# Virtual devices not working on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

My virtual devices on Android Studio do not have the aspect they should have and they do not work:

- the phone case appears huge on the screen, and
- [the screen appears at the normal size but not within the phone case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBNkv.png), and
- the keyboard on virtual device does not work, and
- the keyboard never disappears *

**hence no possibility to click on a button if the button is hidden by the keyboard, etc.*

I tried several things such as entirely reinstalling Android Studio, “playing” with the zoom on the virtual devices, etc. Nothing works.

Would someone know how to fix this issue?

Thank you everyone.

Kind Regards,

David

Comment: you need to share more with us, at least provide screenshot of your running emulator and tell us what screen size do you want

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added a screenshot (2nd bullet point) on which I framed the screen to emphasize the disproportion between phone case and screen. As you will notice, currently the phone case covers most of my computer screen. Kind Regards.

Comment: can you share your xml (or if not possible for privacy , can you share a fake version of it?) i want to test here https://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/

Comment: btw, press the 3 dot, you maybe able to change screen size - https://ibb.co/JcXsG71